# Testing api rest with spring boot error service not inyected

Tags: spring, rest, api, spring-boot, service

I run the test in my application. The service is null when my controller call it.
My Controller. UsuarioService in test is null

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class OrdersController {

    public static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(OrdersController.class);

    @Autowired
    UsuarioService usuarioService;

    // Listado Usuarios
    @ApiOperation(value = "listAllUsers", nickname = "listAllUsers", response = ResponseEntity.class)
    @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Petición Correcta", response = ResponseEntity.class)
    @RequestMapping(value = "/user/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ADMIN_USER') or hasAuthority('STANDARD_USER')")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Usuario>> listAllUsers() {
        List<Usuario> listaUsuarios = usuarioService.findAllUsuarios();
        if (listaUsuarios.isEmpty()) {
            return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<List<Usuario>>(listaUsuarios, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

My Service:

```
@Service
public class UsuarioServiceImpl implements UsuarioService{

    @Autowired
    private UsuarioRepository usuarioRepository;

    @Override
    public Usuario findById(Long id) {
        return usuarioRepository.findOne(id);
    }
```

My test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {JpaConfiguration.class}, initializers= YamlFileApplicationContextInitializer.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@SpringBootTest(
          webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT,
          classes = DemoApplication.class)

@ActiveProfiles("local,default")
public class DemoApplicationTests {


    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new OrdersController()).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void givenNoToken_whenGetSecureRequest_thenUnauthorized() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/api/user/")
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
        .andExpect(status().isUnauthorized())
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.error", is("unauthorized")));
    }
```

When I run my test usuarioService.findAllUsuarios();, usuarioService is null. Can you help me?

I think that something in my test is missing

Answer (score 0):

Please replace the following

`@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {JpaConfiguration.class}, initializers= YamlFileApplicationContextInitializer.class)`

with

`@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest`

I suspect because you have specifed @ContextConfiguration it not using the main classe's @ComponentScan (and thus cannot find the service).

Comment: I tried but not resolve my problem. My service is null too. My principal class is:`@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={"com.example.demo"})
@EnableResourceServer
public class DemoApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
 }
 
 @Override
   protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
       return builder.sources(DemoApplication.class);
   }
 
}`